# How to only include stylesheet on certain routes/pages?

Tags: node.js, templates, express, partial-views, ejs

I have a simple node.js application which has two stylesheets, one for the main page and another for a secondary page.

I also have a header partial which I want to include on both pages, however, one of the stylesheets should only apply to the secondary page. How can I achieve this with only one header patrial?

This is my header partial:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TestApp</title>

        <!--STYLESHEETS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/main.css">

        <!--FONTS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
    </head>
    <body>
```

In my route for the secondary page I tried the following:

```
 res.render("secondary", {data: alldata, path: req.path});
```

Now I wanted to check the path variable in the header partial and depending on the value add a the second stylesheet. I tried the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TestApp</title>

        <!--STYLESHEETS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/main.css">

    <%  
       if path === "/secondary"
       link(rel='stylesheet', href="/stylesheets/secondary.css") 
    %>

        <!--FONTS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
    </head>
    <body>
```

This gives me an 'Unexpected Identifier' error. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any ideas?

Thanks!

### EDIT:

Managed to figure it out...I needed to pass the path to both my primary and secondary page routes otherwise it would error out.

Comment: Can you post the final codes..it will help me too...thanx

Comment: @BaDsHahSHIVAM the code above is exactly what I have now, you will need to pass the path variable from your route like this  res.render("page", { path: req.path });